# List all manually installed packages similar to history.log file

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, history

I searched the whole internet for this but did not find any satisfactory answer for this question.

```
aptitude search ‘~i !~M’ | less
```

does not show the manually installed packages. On my system it shows a huge list:

```
i   accountsservice                 - query and manipulate user account informat
i   acl                             - Access control list utilities             
i   acpi-support                    - scripts for handling many ACPI events     
i   acpid                           - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface
i   add-apt-key                     - Command line tool to add GPG keys to the A
i   adduser                         - add and remove users and groups           
i   alsa-base                       - ALSA driver configuration files           
i   alsa-utils                      - Utilities for configuring and using ALSA  
i   anacron                         - cron-like program that doesn't go by time 
i   apache2                         - Apache HTTP Server                        
i   apache2-bin                     - Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modul
i   apache2-data                    - Apache HTTP Server (common files)         
i   apache2-mpm-prefork             - transitional prefork MPM package for apach
i   apg                             - Automated Password Generator - Standalone 
i   apt                             - commandline package manager               
:
```

and many others...

But obviously I did not install all of these. On the other hand a much more effective solution is this:

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install'
```

Output:

```
Commandline: apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
Commandline: apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Commandline: apt-get install pi
Commandline: apt-get install gparted
Commandline: apt-get install virtualbox
Commandline: apt-get install ardour3
Commandline: apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-extras
Commandline: apt-get install apache2
Commandline: apt-get install tasksel
```

which are exactly the packages I installed manually. But the problem with the above solution is that the logs can be messed up. So what I want is the exact same output of the history.log file from some aptitude command. So that the log messing up won't pose any problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of packages installed locally run this command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

you can save a file list of all installed packages

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > myInstalledPackages.txt
```

Comment: It will also show system packages. Is there a way to get the list minus the system pkgs.